# Avoid syntax error warnings when using string interpolation in SQL query generation

Tags: phpstorm

When using string interpolation, `sprintf` or generally any form of dynamically creating an SQL query string, PhpStorm usually trips up. For example:

```php
$placeholders = join(', ', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ($placeholders)");
$stmt->execute($ids);
```

or:

```php
$db->prepare(sprintf('INSERT .. (%s) ..', $foo))
```

These understandably trigger some sort of SQL syntax error warning in PhpStorm. Is there any way to suppress those without outright disabling SQL language parsing?

Comment: IDE version used? Pure SQL+PHP syntax (first example) should work in **v8** (currently in EAP stage). 2nd example is still far away (as I understand): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2324 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3672

Comment: I see, thanks for those links. I'm currently on 7.1.

Answer (score 8):

I found the definitive answer to this problem from Jetbrains Blog:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/11/database-language-injection-configuration/

You need to add `\%\w+`. in your Tools > Database section.

[image: PhpStorm configuration screenshot]

Comment: Note that it appears to work in `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses, but fails anywhere after a `WHERE` (such as an `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 7):

You can have basic SQL parsing and syntax checking by following these two steps:

1. Set the dialect to `Generic`. In  `File -> Settings` set the following:

[image: PHPStorm settings, "Generic" SQL dialect]
[Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RcDT.png)

2. Then, disable the `SQL dialect detection` inspection:

[image]
[Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dpoj.png)

Confirm with `Ok` and you're done.

Of course it would be great if PHPStorm could resolve SQL Strings with variable substitution, but sadly that's not the case (yet).

Comment: This answer is now outdated for newer IntelliJ/PHPstorm versions. [Emerge's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33054196/2565369) is now the best option.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've come up with is to add a newline before the SQL like:

```
$sql = "\nINSERT INTO ...";
```

PhpStorm thinks it's a plain-old-string now and will not try to parse it as SQL.

Comment: Might as well switch off SQL language injection then, no?

Comment: No, because I want it for my whole project. But in this rare circumstance to ignore. Most PhpStorm warnings/errors can be disabled for a single line with a php annotation above but this doesn't seem to be available for SQL.

Comment: I'd still be reluctant to alter my actual code for the purpose of misdirecting my IDE. I can live with a comment annotation, because it least it's explicit what that's for (don't know if this really is impossible or not). But a hack like this will throw everyone off half a year from now... Having said that, interesting workaround!

Comment: I agree. Plus adding another comment explain why the extra character there is a bit overkill.When that person comes back a year later and goes "that's strange, must be a typo" and they remove it. They will either get an error and they release why it was there or they don't get an error because that issue has been fixed by the IDE in the mean time. Either way no damage done...